# ImportError: cnot import - 'kneeLocator' from 'kneed' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kneed/__init__.py)

Tags: google-colaboratory

I install(pip install kneed) the Kneed, but when I re-run the Import again but it keeps showing me the error(Colad)

1. pip install kneed.
   2.from kneed import kneeLocator(Error).
   ImportError: cannot import name 'kneeLocator' from 'kneed' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kneed/**init**.py)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I guess it is `from kneed import KneeLocator` - `KneeLocator` starts with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste these two lines and see if your problem becomes solved or not:

```
pip install kneed
from kneed import KneeLocator
```

Besides, this is the reference website: https://pypi.org/project/kneed/